# Is there a way to protect my queries m code in excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm trying to protect my m code in excel so when I share my file, my colleagues cant update it. Is there anyway to protect this? Maybe a password protect option for this? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply got around this by hiding the sheet that contains the data using alt+f11 and making the sheet very hidden.

Then I password protected the workbook (review tab).

This method works okay if you dont have to see the data. I'm using the data for power pivot dashboard which is on another tab so works fine for me.